# How to exclude sublinks from GoogleSearch API

Tags: c#, wpf, google-search-api

Hello I have Developed an Application in that I have to pass a keyword and it will give me a first 20 links from Google, I have used GoogleSearchApi for it.

I have used Below menioned code for it

```
 GwebSearchClient client = new GwebSearchClient("Test");
IEnumerable<IWebResult> result = client.Search(keyword.Name.Trim(), 20, "", "", "", "English", "", "uk");
```

but it will give me sublink also which is menioned in `RED` circle in Image

[image]

I don't want sublink can anyone please help me on this?

I got the Result in  IEnumerable result

[image]

Thanks in Advance